# How can I override a parent class function with child one in Perl?

Tags: perl, inheritance, overriding

I would like to replace parent function (Somefunc) in child class, so when I call Main procedure it should fail.

Is it possible in Perl?

Code:

```
package Test;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub Main()
{
    SomeFunc() or die "Somefunc returned 0";
}

sub SomeFunc()
{
    return 1;
}

package Test2;

use strict;
use warnings;

our @ISA = ("Test");

sub SomeFunc()
{
    return 0;
}

package main;

Test2->Main();
```

Comment: In fact I really don't need other OO features, like creating objects, etc.

I just have a lot of base code with 1 or 2 simple procedures to replace in child 'classes'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `Test2->Main()`, the package name is passed as the first parameter to the called function. You can use the parameter to address the right function.

```
sub Main
{
    my ($class) = @_;
    $class->SomeFunc() or die "Somefunc returned 0";
}
```

In this example, `$class` will be `"Test2"`, so you will call `Test2->SomeFunc()`. Even better solution would be to use instances (i.e., `bless` the object in `Test::new`, use `$self` instead of `$class`). And even better would be to use [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose.pm), which solves a lot of problems with object-oriented programming in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

In order for inheritance to work you need to call your functions as methods, either on a class or an object, by using the `->` operator. You seem to have figured this out for your call to `Test2->Main()`, but *all* methods that you want to behave in an OO way must be called this way.

```
package Test;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub Main
{
    my $class = shift;
    $class->SomeFunc() or die "Somefunc returned 0";
}

sub SomeFunc
{
    return 1;
}

package Test2;

our @ISA = ("Test");

sub SomeFunc
{
    return 0;
}

package main;

Test2->Main();
```

See [perlboot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html) for a gentle introduction and [perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html) for more details.

Also, don't put parens after your subroutine names when you declare them -- it doesn't do what you think.