# Accessing class variables in inherited function?

Tags: perl, inheritance

I'm trying to create child classes in Perl that inherit class functions from a single parent. I got it to partially work, using the object method syntax `Child->inheritedMethod()` to call inherited functions outside the child, and `my $class=shift; $class->inheritedMethod();` inside the child class, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305386/how-can-i-override-a-parent-class-function-with-child-one-in-perl/2305413#2305413).

However, for inherited methods, it seems control is passed to parent class, and the method is run in the parent scope with the parent variables. For example, this is in the Parent class:

```
our $VERSION = 0.11;
our $NICKNAME = "Parent Base";
sub version{ $VERSION }
sub whoami{ $NICKNAME }
sub whereami{
  my $class = shift;
  print "should be printing whereami right now...\n";
  print "## In ",(caller(1))[3]," of ",$class->whoami," ",$class->version," in ",__PACKAGE__,"\n"; 
}
```

Each child class declares its own `$VERSION` and `$NICKNAME`, which I hoped would be accessed in place of the parent variables. But when I call `whereami` from the child, it gives
`## Child::Method of Parent Base 0.11 in Parent`.

Questions:

- Is there a way around this? Some other module I should use like Moo(se)? Export all the methods instead of inheritance, which I hear shouldn't be done (polluting the namespace, not a problem here)?
- Would this still be an issue using objects and object
  attributes/variables? I'm trying to avoid it due to my team's
  aversion to object-oriented.
- Is this how inheritance usually works,
  or just Perl? I thought the method would be called within the scope
  of the child class, not passed to the parent.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the method accesses the variable from the lexical scope where it was declared, i.e. the parent class. Class variables are therefore not the same thing as class attributes.

You can access the correct variable by fully qualifying its name (not possible under `strict refs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{   package Parent;
    our $package = 'Parent';

    sub get_package {
        my $class = shift;
        {   no strict 'refs';
            return (caller(0))[3], $class, ${"$class\::package"}
        }
    }
}

{   package Son;
    use parent 'Parent';
    our $package = 'Son';
}

print join ' ', 'Son'->get_package, "\n";
print join ' ', 'Parent'->get_package, "\n";
```

In Moo*, you can use `Moo*X::ClassAttribute`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{   package Parent;
    use Moo;
    use MooX::ClassAttribute;
    class_has package => (is => 'ro',
                          default => 'Parent');

    sub get_package {
        my $class = shift;
        return $class->package;
    }
}

{   package Son;
    use Moo;
    use MooX::ClassAttribute;
    extends 'Parent';
    class_has package => (is => 'ro',
                          default => 'Son');
}

print 'Parent'->get_package, "\n";
print 'Son'->get_package, "\n";
```

Note that MooX::ClassAttribute says

> Overriding class attributes and their accessors in subclasses is not yet supported.

Unlike in Moose, you can't use the `class_has '+package' => (default => 'Son');` syntax for overriding.

Comment: I decided ditch the whole `whoami`/`whereami`/class variable thing in my question since I realized I was getting sidetracked and none of that was relevant to the functionality.
I haven't accepted your answer (but did upvote) since I didn't try it out, and was/am trying to avoid Moose since it imports the `new` method, which could confuse people if the packages aren't supposed to be used as objects.