# Access Fully Qualified Variable Name from Variable in Perl Strict Mode

Tags: perl, oop, strict

I have a series of modules that perform output functions for my scripts. Sometimes the module is called directly -- it is called `View` -- and sometimes a child class that extends it is used instead (`View::ChildName`). View declares `our $THEMENAME = 'default';` when it is loaded, but the child declares its own specific `$THEMENAME` when it loads.

Problem: When `new()` is called on a child theme, it calls `my $self = $class->next::method(%params);` (using `mro`) to get some core things set by the parent class before extending it. One of the core bits is that the parent class sets `$self->{'themeName'}`. However, if it simply calls `$THEMENAME`, it gets the parent's setting:  "default."

The only way I've reliably and successfully solved this is to turn off `strict` temporarily and do this:

```
my $packName = ref $self;

{ 
    no strict;
    $self->{'themeName'} = ${${packName} . "::THEMENAME"};
}
```

This works, but in profiling the code, if objects are created frequently, this actually adds more overhead than I expected. I tried the alternative of always using the parent's package name, e.g. the child sets `$View::THEMENAME`. This *works*, but only if the theme name is set within `new` and not on the load of the module; if it is on load, there is erratic behavior if several different child objects (of different children) are created over the course of the script.

These options both seem less than ideal. Is there a good way to do this? The only thing I found was [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991557/accessing-class-variables-in-inherited-function) and I think incorporating `Moo` would probably add more overhead than I'm trying to avoid by getting rid of my current `no strict` block. Has anything been added to more modern versions of Perl that might solve my issue?

The alternative is to dodge the issue all together and simply set `$self->{'themeName'}` within each child object's `new` method, although I'm trying to avoid that change since there's a fair number of legacy child classes that expect `$THEMENAME` to exist.

---

Minimal reproducible example of View.pm:

```
use strict;
package View;

our $THEMENAME = 'default';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $params = shift;
    my $self = { 'setting' => $params{'setting'} };

    bless $self, $class;

    $self->{'themeName'} = $THEMENAME;
    return $self;  
}
```

And of `View/Child.pm`:

```
use strict;
use mro;
package View::Child;

use parent 'View';

our $THEMENAME = 'child';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $params = shift;
    my $self = $class->next::method($params);

    bless $self, $class;

    say STDOUT $self->{'themeName'};
    # Prints 'default' not 'child'.

    return $self;  
}
```

Now a script to call it:

```
use View::Child;
my $object = View::Child->new();
```

If you added the first code block to `View.pm`, it gives the expected result instead, but seems to add about 9 ms to each call to `new` -- more than the time it takes for it to handle everything else I have in the much longer full length `new` method -- which adds up if the program runs many iterations:

```
use strict;
package View;

our $THEMENAME = 'default';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $params = shift;
    my $self = { };

    bless $self, $class;

    my $packName = ref $self;

    { 
         no strict;
         $self->{'themeName'} = ${${packName} . "::THEMENAME"};
    }  
    return $self;  
}
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal runnable example? That would help clarify your question. See [mcve]

Comment: @HåkonHægland I've added one. Thanks!

Comment: This line returns `undef` in your current example: `my $self = $class->next::method($params);`

Comment: Oh! I mixed up notation on the file names when describing the files, I think: It should be `View/Child.pm` not `View::Child.pm`. Maybe that's the issue? (For the demo code, not my question, that is.)

Comment: Why can't you just set the theme name in the child constructor after having called the parent contructor?

Comment: The child should not be doing `bless $self, $class;`

Comment: It seems like you might need to be have a `can` function override for the child class but I've never had to implement one myself, so I can't give a more complete answer.  I do know that in general `can` functions will indicate whether or not a function is implemented for a module, and if there was something that you needed to ask `child` to do, you had to ask `child` if it could with `can`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of class properties is one you should forget (in Perl). It's fine for the module to have constants and possibly variables, but they shouldn't be considered part of the class.

I see four approaches you could take:

- Update the property in the child's constructor.
- Provide the value as a parameter
- Override the accessor
- Provide the default as a method

##### Update the property in the child's constructor

```perl
# View.pm
sub new {
    my ($class, $params) = @_;
    my $self = bless({}, $class);

    $self->{ setting   } = $params->{ setting };
    $self->{ themeName } = 'default';

    return $self;  
}

sub themeName { $_[0]->{themeName} }  # Optional
```

```perl
# Child/View.pm
sub new {
    my ($class, $params) = @_;
    my $self = $class->next::method($params);

    $self->{ themeName } = 'child';

    return $self;
}
```

##### Provide the value as a parameter

```perl
# View.pm
sub new {
    my ($class, $params) = @_;
    my $self = bless({}, $class);

    $self->{ setting   } = $params->{ setting   };
    $self->{ themeName } = $params->{ themeName } // 'default';

    return $self;  
}

sub themeName { $_[0]->{themeName} }  # Optional
```

```perl
# Child/View.pm
sub new {
    my ($class, $params) = @_;
    my $self = $class->next::method({ themeName => 'child', %$params });
    return $self;
}
```

##### Override the accessor

```perl
# View.pm
sub new {
    my ($class, $params) = @_;
    my $self = bless({}, $class);

    $self->{ setting } = $params->{ setting };

    return $self;  
}

sub themeName { 'default' }
```

```perl
# Child/View.pm

# No need to override `new`.

sub themeName { 'child' }
```

##### Provide the default as a method

```perl
# View.pm
sub new {
    my ($class, $params) = @_;
    my $self = bless({}, $class);

    $self->{ setting   } = $params->{ setting };
    $self->{ themeName } = $class->defaultThemeName;

    return $self;  
}

sub defaultThemeName { 'default' }

sub themeName { $_[0]->{themeName} }  # Optional
```

```perl
# Child/View.pm

# No need to override `new`.

sub defaultThemeName { 'child' }
```

Answer (score 2):

One potential solution would be to add THEMENAME as an overridable method.

View.pm:

```perl
use strict;
package View;

our $THEMENAME = 'default';

sub THEMENAME {return 'default'}

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $params = shift;
    my $self = { 'setting' => $params->{'setting'} };

    bless $self, $class;

    $self->{'themeName'} = $self->THEMENAME;
    return $self;  
}
```

View/Child.pm:

```perl
use strict;
use mro;
package View::Child;

use parent 'View';

our $THEMENAME = 'child';

sub THEMENAME {return 'child'}

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $params = shift;
    my $self = $class->next::method($params);

    bless $self, $class;

    say STDOUT $self->{'themeName'};
    # Prints 'default' not 'child'.
    #
    return $self;  
}
```

```sh
# perl -Mlib=. -MView::Child -e 'View::Child->new()'
child
```

Answer (score 1):

My final solution follows what @plentyofcoffee and @ikegami outlined, but I wanted to see if I could come up with a way to set it automatically without each child module implementing it (keeping in mind legacy code). Assuming the child does want to set it, it passes $param{'themeName'} to the parent's constructor, which sets it to `$self->{'themeName'}`. If `themeName` is undefined, I came up with this regex in the parent class that extracts the name of the child as a fallback `themeName`:

```
unless ($self->{'themeName'}) {
    state $getThemeNameRegEx = qr#^SAFARI::(.*::)+(.*?)$#; 
    $class =~ /$getThemeNameRegEx/;
    $self->{'themeName'} = $2 // "default"; 
}
```

This sets to `default` if the name doesn't contain at least two levels below `SAFARI`, e.g. `SAFARI::View` is `default` (the parent module is in use without a child) and `SAFARI::View::mysite` is `mysite`.